# MySQL which trigger to use to limit entry number?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table Products

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `transactionnumber` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customerID` mediumint(6) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `product` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `datebought` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transactionnumber`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_unique` (`customerID`,`product`,`datebought`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_unipr` (`customerID`,`product`),
  KEY `product` (`product`),
  CONSTRAINT `prod_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customerID`) REFERENCES `custdetails` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `prod_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`product`) REFERENCES `product catalogue` (`Itemdescription`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=63 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

I am trying to add a trigger which would prevent anyone inserting any products if a customerID is already associated with 10 products.

I tried writing something like this

```
Delimiter ^^
CREATE TRIGGER maxfiveproducts BEFORE INSERT on Products 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
if ((SELECT CustomerID, Count(*) from products GROUP BY CustomerID)>10) then
signal allstate '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No more than 10 products per customer!';
end if;
end
^^
Delimiter ;
```

I am aware that my code may be bad as I have just started learning about triggers and can't find this specific example anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would look more like this:

```
Delimiter ^^
CREATE TRIGGER maxfiveproducts BEFORE INSERT on Products 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    set @cnt = (select count(*) from products p where p.customerId = new.customerId);
    if (@cnt >= 10) then
        signal allstate '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No more than 10 products per customer!';
    end if;
end;
Delimiter ;
```

Why is the name "maxfiveproducts"?

Comment: sorry, was meant to be ten! But the name doesn't change anything

Comment: Thank you so much, the code worked, although I had to change several things, e.g. @cnt only worked when adjusted to >9 not 10, not sure why! But thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DECLARE` to declare the variable, store the `COUNT` in it and write an `IF` condition, e.g.:

```
CREATE TRIGGER pgl_new_user 
BEFORE INSERT ON Products FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE existing_products integer;

    SET @existing_products := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Products WHERE customerID = NEW.customerID);

    IF(@existing_products >= 10) THEN
        SIGNAL ALLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No more than 10 products per customer!';
    END IF;    

END//
```